# Spark 1.3.1: cannot read file from S3 bucket, org/jets3t/service/ServiceException

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-s3, apache-spark, hadoop2

I'm on an AWS EC2 VM (Ubuntu 14.04), willing to do some basics with Spark on RDDs from my S3 files. While running successfully this dirty command (not using `sparkContext.hadoopConfiguration` for the moment)

```
scala> val distFile = sc.textFile("s3n://< AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID>:<AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY>@bucketname/folder1/folder2/file.csv")
```

I then get the following error when running a `distFile.count()`

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/jets3t/service/ServiceException
         at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3native.NativeS3FileSystem.createDefaultStore(NativeS3FileSystem.java:334)
         at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3native.NativeS3FileSystem.initialize(NativeS3FileSystem.java:324)
         at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.createFileSystem(FileSystem.java:2596)
...
...
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.jets3t.service.ServiceException
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
```

I have previously

- defined an AWS IAM user with corresponding AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID and AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY
- added the `export` of both keys as env variables in .bashrc
- built Spark 1.3.1 with `SPARK_HADOOP_VERSION=2.6.0-cdh5.4.1 sbt/sbt assembly`
- installed and run hadoop **2.6-cdh5.4.1** (pseudo distributed)

Does it have to do with the syntax of the `textFile("s3n// ...")` ? I've tried others, including `s3://` without success ...

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Include Jets3t jar to your class-path. Add proper compatible version with your current setting.  You need ServiceException to be added to your class path.

Comment: It helped! Thanks!

Comment: Can you please explain how to do this? I am running a jupyter notebook and it gives the same error.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. In spite it occurred at spark v2.1.0 with hadoop v2.7.2 environment, however I left it here because it would be the same cause. Here's what I've got.

```
A needed class was not found. This could be due to an error in your runpath. Missing class: org/jets3t/service/ServiceException
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/jets3t/service/ServiceException
at      org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3native.NativeS3FileSystem.createDefaultStore(NativeS3FileSystem.java:342)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3native.NativeS3FileSystem.initialize(NativeS3FileSystem.java:332)
at
...
...
 Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.jets3t.service.ServiceException
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
```

It was because of the classpath got the lower version of `net.java.dev.jets3t:jets3t` dependency than what `org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-aws` required.

I solved the problem after adding `net.java.dev.jets3t:jets3t:0.9.0` in my build.sbt

Comment: could you please tell me where can I find build.sbt?

Answer (score 0):

You need to include hadoop-mapreduce-client jars in your CLASSPATH. In my case, I made my own distribution with these dependencies.

I put the following files in the lib folder:

- hadoop-mapreduce-client-jobclient-2.6.0.jar
- hadoop-mapreduce-client-hs-plugins-2.6.0.jar
- hadoop-mapreduce-client-shuffle-2.6.0.jar
- hadoop-mapreduce-client-jobclient-2.6.0-tests.jar
- hadoop-mapreduce-client-common-2.6.0.jar
- hadoop-mapreduce-client-app-2.6.0.jar
- hadoop-mapreduce-client-hs-2.6.0.jar
- hadoop-mapreduce-client-core-2.6.0.jar

Comment: Hi, after finding where were the jars located, I've run this command `./spark-1.3.1/bin/spark-shell -classpath /usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/*` but still get the exact same error when running a `distFile.count()`

Comment: Try to put those jars in the lib folder of the Spark.

Comment: Actually I've found the jars in Spark's folder **lib_managed/jars** so I've run `./spark-1.3.1/bin/spark-shell -classpath spark-1.3.1/lib_managed/jars/*` but unfortunately still get same jets3t error: `Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.jets3t.service.S3ServiceException`

Comment: I've also used command `spark-shell --jars $(echo /home/ubuntu/spark-1.3.1/lib_managed/jars/*.jar | tr ' ' ',') ` following thread "Spark-Shell: Howto define JAR loading order" and got the **same** error. I've also given open/upload permissions to my S3 files, just in case.